# Getting Access form field values in SQL string in the VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I may be asking silly question as I am very new in ms access and VBA and stuck with this,

I am having a SQL string in my Access VBA as below example

```
select customer_id from customer_table where customer_name in ('Max','Jack')
```

I want user to add/replace the customer_name in the query using a *ms access Unbound text box* name as **txtCusName**. I tried to modify the SQL string as below but getting compilation error, advice me where I am doing the mistake?

```
select customer_id from customer_table where customer_name in ( & Me.txtCusName & )
```

Again, this is just example and I have bigger query for my project and which is working if I hardcoded the values but wondering how I can get from access form.

Comment: perhaps read a basic tutorial?

Comment: I totally agree, thanks for the advice and will be great if you could share the solution for this.

Comment: internet has many tutorial resources.

Comment: I could have used this one _customer_name = " & "'" & Me.txtCusName & "'"_ if a single value but wondering how I can get the text in the SQL "IN" function, that is where I am lost.

Comment: Expecting a user to properly format the required string is simply asking for trouble and not user-friendly. You (and your users) would be better off if you populate a listbox with available values and construct what you need from the selected items.

Comment: All I want to know is can I get the values from a access form unbound field inside a SQL query using "IN" function so that user can add many filters as much as they want in one shot rather than one value from a field? Comeon, this is not so hard for you guys though it is for me, I am sure you will not lose anything if you teach that much, appreciate!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote like the below code to allow user to just type as 'Max','Jack' in form field to get the query filter and works.

```
select customer_id from customer_table where customer_name in ( " & "" & Me.txtCusName & ")"
```